# PHP in IIS with external physical path

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, external

We're attempting to access a .html file over the network, to be handled by our IIS.

Our setup is as follows:

SRV1 has IIS 7.5 installed along with PHP (mappings included).
SRV2 has the files that are to be used by the IIS.

We've changed the physical path on the IIS (\SRV2\Sites) and it does correctly read our web.config (which points to a .html file with php coding). The html part of the file works when you browse to the IIS site (it shows the title in the browser), however, the php part of the file *does not show*.
As soon as it has something to do with php, it does not work.

php works if it's placed locally on the IIS but not when the file(s) is being pulled from an external site - which we're trying to do in our case.

Any tips?

Comment: Im guessing the PHP extension is not triggering because the server thinks the .html is not a .php file... rename the file to php?

Comment: Yea we were using a .php file as well which didn't do anything at all. Changing php.ini fixed this and it all works now. Cheers.